Source files in multiple subdirectories with CMake
I have the following directory structure:
CMakeLists.txt
src
--main.cpp
--VulkanApplication.cpp & .h
--vk_utils
----instance_utils.cpp
----vk_utils.h

Now in main.cpp an Object of type VulkanApplication is instantiated and initVulkan is called. initVulkan then calls  createInstance which is defined in vk_utils.h and implemented in instance_utils.h. VulkanApplication.cpp #includes vk_utils/vk_utils.h.
Now I am attempting to compile and link the whole thing into one application that performs the call chain main()->app.run()->initVulkan()->createInstance(). I use CMake for compilation with the following CMakeLists.txt:
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.5)
project(VKRaytracer CXX)

set(SOURCE_FILES 
    src/main.cpp 
    src/VulkanApplication.cpp 
    src/vk_utils/instance_utils.cpp
    )

add_executable(${PROJECT_NAME} ${SOURCE_FILES})
target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} glfw vulkan dl pthread X11 Xxf86vm Xrandr Xi)

But upon linking (I think) I get the following error:
[build] ld: CMakeFiles/VKRaytracer.dir/src/VulkanApplication.cpp.o: in function `VulkanApplication::initVulkan()':
[build] src/VulkanApplication.cpp:20:(.text+0x1): undefined reference to `createInstance()'
[build] collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status

Now I am completely new to CMake and the CPP build ecosystem and just do not understand how I am supposed to link the files inside the vk_utils folder such that the VulkanApplication class can find them. Is structuring your code into directories really this hard in CPP?
EDIT:
As requested the minimal example code:
main.cpp:
#include "VulkanApplication.h"

int main()
{
    VulkanApplication app;
    app.run();

}

VulkanApplication.cpp:
#include "VulkanApplication.h"
#include "vk_utils/vk_utils.h"

void VulkanApplication::run()
{

    this->initVulkan();

}

void VulkanApplication::initVulkan() {
    createInstance();
}

VulkanApplication.h:
#ifndef VULKAN_APPLICATION_H
#define VULKAN_APPLICATION_H


class VulkanApplication
{

public:
  void run();

private:

  void initVulkan();
};
#endif

instance_utils.h:
#ifndef INSTANCE_UTILS
#define INSTANCE_UTILS

void *createInstance(); //type changed to void* as POC that it works without external libs
#endif

instance_utils.cpp:
#include "vk_utils.h"

void* create_instance()
{
    return nullptr;
}


Can you add the code where the missing function is called and where it is implemented? Ideally you'd want to put together a [mcve] which could help you find the problem on your own.

You are declaring the function createInstance but are defining the function create_instance.

Yet another proof that source code is rarely well written at 2am. Thank's!
